# Having problems when checking for arguments

Tags: java, bukkit

When I try to run the command `/squid` it works but when I do `/squid set` or `/squid start` nothing happens.

The command should tell you that the location was set or that the event has started, but it doesn't. There are no errors in the console, and I do not get any feedback either.

```
package me.mcmatt.squidcp;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.WorldEditPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {


  public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Squid CP booted up! Version: " + Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("SquidCarePackages").getDescription().getVersion());

  }
  public void onDisable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Squid CP shut down!");
  }

  public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    if (commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("squid")) {
      if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must be a player to run this command");
      } else {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if (args.length == 0) {
          player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "----Commands----");
          player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "/squid -" + ChatColor.AQUA + " Displays this message");
          player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "/squid set -" + ChatColor.AQUA + " Sets the area at wich the squids spawn");
          player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "/squid start -" + ChatColor.AQUA + " Starts the squid care package");
          player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Plugin created by McMatt, @McMattGames");

        } else {
          if (args.length == 1) {
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("set")) {
              player.sendMessage("Area Set!");
            } else {
              if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
                player.sendMessage("Starting!");
              } else {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Invalid Arguments!");

              }

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return true;

  }

  public WorldEditPlugin getWorldEdit() {
    Plugin p = Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("WorldEdit");
    if (p instanceof WorldEditPlugin) return (WorldEditPlugin) p;
    else return null;

  }

}
```

Comment: Are there any aliases to the command that you are using instead? (for example, did you make `sq` an alias of `squid`, and you're using that for testing)

Comment: Also, can you paste your plugin.yml?

Answer (score 1):

You are not taking in consideration multiple things about Java and the command system.

First of all, you should make use of `else if` when needed. This prevents you from duplicating code.
For example, you can use `else if` like this:

```
if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("set")) {
    player.sendMessage("Area Set!");
} else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
    player.sendMessage("Starting!");
} else {
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Invalid Arguments!");
}
```

Second, do not use `commandLabel`. You should be using `command.getName()` instead. This is because the command label is a volatile value; it changes if you use an alias to your command (e. g. using `/s` instead of `/squid`).

Third, please be sure you inserted the command name in the Plugin YAML. Your YML file should have at least these lines:

```
commands:
  squid:
```